# Do Shared Components only work with matching framework in NX?

Tags: reactjs, angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Looks like in nx you can make shared libraries. I have seen angular, react, web ui libraries. However, does the framework/library have to be compatible? Can a react component library export components to an angular application? My guess is no. But something like web components or lit elements could be?

I tried to add a react component from react library into an angular app

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: it's been a few years since I've researched this... so this might be a little outdated.

> Looks like in nx you can make shared libraries.

`Nx` is mostly a tool for organizing and building code and generally doesn't know or care about what type of framework(s) or libraries you are using. Most importantly, Nx does nothing to make multiple libraries compatible with each other. The solution to your problem will be the same regardless of whether you are using Nx or not.

> Can a react component library export components to an angular application?

Sort of... not without some additional work (keep reading)...

> But something like web components or lit elements could be?

Web components are nice because they can act like little sandboxes which are isolated from the surrounding page. It's sort of like having most of the benefits of an iframe without all of the crappiness of an iframe.

Some frameworks like Vue, Stencil, and I'm sure others let you compile directly to web-components (ie. custom html elements) which are ready to be consumed anywhere. React does not have such a feature. Furthermore react has been historically bad about working with custom html elements ([read more here](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components#custom-html-elements)). It is my recollection that react is the only library/framework that doesn't play nicely with web components.

No matter the case, you should be able to use web components (eg. lit) to wrap your framework-specific components in order to be able to use them anywhere. For example, you could create a react web component wrapper. It could check if react has been downloaded, if not, download it and then instantiate your react component inside of a web component. Does that make sense? There is a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-webcomponent) that already does this for you.

**Final note:**

For the past 5 years or so there has been a focus on "micro-frontends", similar to microservices on the backend. The idea is that you create little mini-apps and compose them together into one larger app. Similar to microservices, each mini-app could be owned and built by a different team using a different framework... but you can still use them all inside a larger application. So what you are wanting should be do-able and well documented, but it'll probably be different for every framework/library.

Comment: Solid answer. Thank you

Comment: Thanks! If you like the answer, it's customary to "accept" it so that others know that this solution worked for you.